# how to make sizeof enum as char size in C in visual c++ IDE

Tags: c, visual-c++, enums, pragma

I'm writing C program in VC++ 2008 I have below structure and enum.

**test.h**

```
#ifndef _TEST_H_
#define _TEST_H_

typedef enum Selection
{
    None,
    Single,
    Multiple
} Selection_T;

typedef struct Test_struct
{
    char var1;
    char var2;

    Selection_T sel;
} Test_struct_T;

#endif
```

**test.c**

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "test.h"
Test_struct_T test_obj = { 1, 2, Multiple };

int main()
{
    char *pbyte = (char *)&test_obj;

    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(test_obj);i++)
        printf ("%x\n",*(pbyte+i));

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

I want sel should start from 3rd byte in structure but the compiler treating enum as integer so sel starts from 5th byte after (2 holes) please help me to make compiler treating enum as byte so sel should start from 3rd byte of the structure.
If there are Pragmas it'll be useful for me.
Thanks Advance

Comment: Read about [`#pragma pack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx).

Comment: Even if your compiler will treat enums as bytes (see Dabo answer) it won't save you from structure alignment (see Joachim comment). Put them together...

Answer (score 4):

In C++11 you can declare a [scoped enum](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#enum) with an [underlying type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) other than the default of `int`. For instance:

```
typedef enum Selection: unsigned char
{
    None,
    Single,
    Multiple
} Selection_T;
```

In C++, prior to the C++11 standard, or C this is not possible. The implementation determines the representation of an `enum`. In the case of the Microsoft compiler, an `enum` is represented as an `int`.

If you wish to use a single byte to store this information, it follows that you cannot use an `enum` and instead you should use `unsigned char`.

It is true that you could pack your struct, but this has disadvantages. You will now have misaligned data, and your variable is still 4 bytes wide.

Comment: Hi @David Heffernan Thanks for reply I tried This but this will work for C++ program but doesn't work for C program.I required for C Program

Comment: Sorry, I had not spotted that detail. In which case you cannot use an enum to meet your needs.

Comment: when i run the program the memory space it is taking as 12002000 that is since enum is considered as a int its taking 4bytes as memory space but i want enum to be considered as a char i.e just a byte so that i can avoid those holes formation in between which will save my memory. i.e the output of the C program also should be something like 122 only is it possible to make C compiler to take enum as Char as in the case of CPP also ? @david

Comment: I answered that already. The compiler you use represents enums as `int`. You have to use `unsigned char`.

Comment: @ david i have used unsigned char but it is not working for C program what you said works fine for CPP(test.cpp)  program but for me its not working for C program(test.c)

Comment: You don't understand me. As I say in the answer, and as you yourself pointed out, in the MS C compiler, an enum is always represented by an `int`. Therefore you cannot use an enum if you want it to be a single byte. Stop using an enum and use `unsigned char`.

Comment: It's OK. I can see how that could have happened and I've tried to make the answer a little clearer.

Comment: If the Microsoft compiler uses int as the underlying type in an enum, how come a lot of Microsoft-defined enums contain a sentinel value to force it to be a 32-bit enum? Seems contradictory to me.

Comment: @TomLint Some possible reasons. They might have not have wanted to be tied to an implementation detail that could change. They might also have wanted to allow other compilers to use the header files. They might have wanted to be explicit so that there was no room for doubt. The code may have originated from times when the default base type was a different type.

Answer (score 1):

In some circumstances, this may be helpful:

```
typedef uint8_t Selection_t;
enum Selection_enum
{
    None,
    Single,
    Multiple
};

/* Selection_t is of size 8 */
typedef struct Test_struct
{
    char var1;
    char var2;

    Selection_T sel;
} Test_struct_T;
```

On one hand type `Selection_t` has size 8 and can be used for variable and function parameter type.
On the other hand you can use the enum values for assignation that are of type `int` by default but the compiler will cast them immediately when assigned to a `Selection_t` type variable.

Also, if you do something unsafe like defining and using a `sel = 0xFFFF,` the compiler will warn you with following message:

> warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]

Answer (score 0):

In MSVC the following is a workable construct that I use:

```
typedef enum {
    zero,
    one
} Int;

struct test {
    Int first:8;
    int fill:24;
};

void main(int argc, char **argv) {
struct test mine[1];

    mine->first = zero;
}
```

Comment: what will sizeof(mine->first) be? Im presuming 4,assuming int is 4

Comment: size of mine is 4, and size of the bit field first is not allowed.  You can do the math and first is 1, and fill is 3 since together they equal 4.